# Is it possible to run Java DB from read-only media in embedded mode?

Tags: javadb

I want to use Java DB in embedded mode in a Java application running from a CD-ROM. Does anyone have any experience of doing this? Will it work? The database will only have selects issued against it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible: [Deploying the database on the read-only media](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cscv/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cloudscape.doc/rdevdvlp38881.html)

Also I have noted select statements work when the database is owned by root with all write access withdrawn and is accessed by a non-privileged user.